# Flask Plotly Responsive in Browser

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plotly

How to make this plotly chart responsive in index.html - I create a flask app and js function for rendering the plot, however, I cannot figure out, how to make it responsive. What is wrong with variable config - it seems not to work.

Thank you

Flask:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():

    locations = sorted(df['location'].unique())
    rooms = sorted(df['rooms'].unique())

    # Visualisation
    import json
    import plotly
    import plotly.express as px
    df.rooms = df.rooms.astype(str)
    fig = px.scatter(df, x="m2", y="price", trendline="ols", color="rooms", symbol='rooms',
                                marginal_x="histogram", 
                                marginal_y="rug",
                                template='plotly_dark', hover_data=['price', 'rooms', 'm2', 'location'],
                                title="Real Estate in Vienna")
    
    graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)

    return render_template('index.html', locations=locations, rooms=rooms, graphJSON=graphJSON)
```

JavaScript:

```
                    <!-- Visualisation -->
                    {%block content%}
                    <div class="card mb-4 m-auto" style="width: 90%">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div id="chart"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endblock %}

    <!-- Plotly -->
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var graphs = {{ graphJSON | safe}};
        var config = {responsive: true};
        Plotly.newPlot("chart", graphs, {}, config);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using `Plotly.newPlot()` wrong. By reading the [API reference](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlynewplot) you will see, that there are to different signatures for this function:

1. `Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, data, layout, config)`
2. `Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, obj)`

Looks you were mixing both up since the Python function

`graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)`

returns a single object with keys for `data`, `layout`, `config` and `frames` with defaults to `{data: [], layout: {}, config: {}, frames: []}`.

Thus everything should work if you use the following JavaScript that extracts the parameters `data` and `layout` from the object `charts` and then use

`Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, data, layout, config)`

instead of

`Plotly.newPlot(graphDiv, obj)`:

```
<!-- Plotly -->
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = {{graphJSON | safe}};
    var data = chart["data"];
    var layout = chart["layout"];
    var config = {responsive: true};
    Plotly.newPlot("chart", data, layout, config);
</script>
```